# Dictionary element flow in iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary

I have problem with Dictionary, when i get data from NSMutableDictonary at that time change flow of element every time. So please help me.....

Like,

```
NSMutableDictionary *param = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"a",@"A",@"b",@"B",@"c",@"C",@"d",@"D",@"e",@"E", nil];
NSArray *keys = [param allKeys];
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: first time get - {a,b,e,d,c}  second time - {e,b,c,a,d} .........

Comment: What do you want to get with these code? And did you get? Please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

There is no order in key-value pairs in NSDictionary. For example in NSSet there is no order either. 
You need to sort elements in your array using for example `NSSortDescriptor` or `sortedArrayUsingSelector` or `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator`. Last two methods are NSArray methods.

Answer (score 0):

**NSDictionary** is not like an **array**, it is just like ***a set of objects***. You can access all of your values by it **key**.

But you need to shored keys, you can do it by this way

```
NSArray *keys = [param allKeys];
keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *a, NSString *b) {
    return [a compare:b];
}];
```

Comment: In other words a dictionary is unordered, unlike an array, which is ordered.

Comment: no one is ordered. sql query gets an ordered data from table. if you need strictly maintain then you are recommended to use "sortedArrayUsingComparator"

Comment: "no one is ordered"?  Huh?

Comment: actually yes it it is 'no one'. nsarray,nsdictionary,nsset

Comment: this your additional job using comparator or sort descriptor can do this

Comment: it is ordered as inputed opdered

Comment: I don't know what you are waffling on about.  You are making up your own terms for well-established concepts and you are unable to describe them.  An array is ordered and a dictionary is unordered.  The end.

Comment: NSArray *orderdArray = @[@"D",@"A",@"C",@"E",@"B"];

Comment: output:
    D,
    A,
    C,
    E,
    B

Comment: NSDictionary *orderdDictionay = @{@"d":@"D",@"a":@"A",@"c":@"C",@"e":@"E",@"b":@"B"};

Comment: output:

    a = A;
    b = B;
    c = C;
    d = D;
    e = E;

Comment: look which one is sorted NSArray or NSDictionary

Comment: You don't appear to understand the difference between "sorted" and "ordered". I never said anything about sorting.